# What was wrong with the review? Am I being incorrectly penalized for it?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts

**My assessment:**

This question [continuous video stream call using html5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23168278/1309352) is a low effort question. The way I see it, it doesn't provide much explanation either.

**What happened:**

This question landed in my Low-quality [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4703074). I had a good hunch that this was in fact an audit. I knew that since it had a high vote count therefore recommending close will fail me in the audit. But yet I did recommend close for it. Most of my previous audit which I have failed are for the very same reason (one of them was a wrong click, I guess), if I'm not mistaken. Anyways, now I'm being penalized for that review which *I* think was a weak audit and review banned for 2 days.

**Question:**

Was my assessment of the question right? If not, then what did I miss? How was I wrong in it?

And if so, then can I have the ban lifted?

Comment: The review questions that appear in the queues are selected automatically under certain circumstances. If you feel this shouldn't be one of them, simply downvote it (or cast a close vote when you'll have 3k+ reputation).

Answer (score 4):

If you identified it as a low-effort question, the correct response is to downvote it, not close it.  There are no close reasons that correspond to "low effort."

That said, I'm a bit baffled that such a low quality question got so many upvotes.  I've closed it as "insufficient information to diagnose."  Even the lone answerer said as much.

Comment: I was just about to ask you about that.  Kind of seemed like the left hand didn't quite agree with what the right hand was typing.

Comment: I would have opted for "unclear what you're asking". Since it's closed now, would it mean that my action on that review was right? And have my ban lifted?

Comment: Seems due to the bounty. When people are listing the bounty questions, they tend to upvote lots of them (a good number not deserving it). That's a phenomenon I don't understand, though, as if the question hadn't a bounty they probably wouldn't upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what's wrong with the question?

I can see a couple of things that make it a lesser quality:

- Spelling
- Excessive use of bold
- No complete sentences
- Lack of [useful] capitalization of any kind

...but that alone doesn't make the question fit to be **closed**.

There is a clear problem here that is being addressed, and there is code provided to illustrate the problem that they're having.  It really *could* do with more explanation from the OP as to the goal of it, even though that's not entirely necessary.

It doesn't really seem like much effort was put behind the question. I would recommend a downvote instead of a close vote.